# convert candidate to account salesforce

Tags: salesforce

i am new in salesforce sales cloud. I created custom fields in candidate, but When I transform on account I do not see those fields. Is there any configuration for that? Or should I create those same fields in accounts?

Thanks friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create them on Accounts as well.  Each table must be configured independently.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create fields in both objects and then map them thru Lead Conversion Mapping in setup. Then when you convert lead to account, you will see that the content will be transferred.